# Does non-numlocked 5 send keycodes?

Tags: windows, keyboard, numlock

On my laptop, on the numeric keypad, all the other numeric keys send keycodes (Up, Down, Left, Right, Home, End, Pg Up, Pg Dn, Del, Ins) when num lock is disabled, apart from number 5 in the middle.

Does it send any code at all, or is it blocked by the keyboard's logic? (like Fn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

It sends the keycode `101` (i.e. number `5`) when the num lock is on.

It sends the keycode `12` (i.e. `Clear`) when num lock is off.